# Recommended way to design a multi language recipe database in SQL (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, localization

Basically, I'm kinda exhausted while thinking about the best possible way to structure my database for a recipe app I have planned and could need some help/ideas.
The goal is to make a recipe app including **multiple languages**(translated recipes) and which has features like a meal plan and shopping list, for example.

To achieve all that, I came up with this design of a database(Image below). It's important to have the ingredients as an own entity so that they add up in the shopping list. With the current design its really hard to filter by the total amount of calories, eg. "I want to see all recipes that have less than 500 calories".
The recipes only get added by me, meaning there will be probably never ever be more than 10 000 of them(In the absolute best case :D).

I would appreciate any help and also comments about other things like scalabilty/performance etc.

[image: Database design]

Comment: you could add manually (or generate it with a script with sum of all ingredients) the calories from 1 recipe for one person and multiply by number of persons, as the number of ingredients must increase with higher numbers and that much the calories will not increase for a specific ingredient

Comment: You cannot ask for a general review of your design here. Please ask a specific question.